# Images in android app

Tags: android, image, drawable

I see three folders within my eclipse project drawable-hdpi,mdpi,ldpi

Do I need to put images in all three of these folders?Or can I just use one of them.My images
seem to scale fairly well.I do not want to have duplicate images if it is uneccessary.

I guess what I am asking is will the app be able to find my images if I just use one of the above mentioned folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically if you drop them in mdpi, I believe all devices 1.6 and above will find them. However, if you support below 1.6 devices you'll need to duplicate the drawable-mdpi resources and call it just drawable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will find the `Drawable`s regardless of which directory you use. You can also just have a `drawable` directory if you don't plan to support different densities.